# Generic accounts without Sharepoint access stuck logging in

Tags: adfs, sso

We have a series of generic accounts which we use for generic workstations. Our sharepoint implementation has not licensed these generic accounts as its quite expensive. All these users have personal accounts, but have a decade long habit of using generic accounts for quick activities.

Due to SSO these accounts try to automatically log into Sharepoint (via ADFS from the Windows signon) but seems to just get stuck. It isn't able to terminate the login gracefully and ends up just looping.

Is there a way to stop the automated login and prompt the user for their personal AD login before it tries to auto login? I think there should be a workaround but cant find one for the life of me

Cheers